# Verb meaning to advance through time

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word that could be used as a verb to mean to advance through time?

For example, in the sentence: *with this jump, I advanced 15 seconds through time!* It's used pretty often, which becomes heavy to read, so instead, they would say something along the lines of *I {verbed} 15 seconds with this jump!*

I thought of using **update** or **progress** but you would need a lot of context clues to understand they're not used the way you expect them to.

Comment: Would 'prolong' fit?

Comment: One (I suppose) **travels** through time.

Comment: @TheRookieCoder I don't think so no

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, I could replace *advance* with travel, move or any verb of movement really. I'm looking for a way not to say "through time", preferably replace the whole thing with a single verb

Comment: Ah, then you "aged by 15 seconds/years".

Comment: You could use _jump_ figuratively and it works well with the literal sense of _jump_ in your context. "I've jumped 15 seconds (into the future)".

Comment: @WeatherVane He seems to be talking about time travel, not normal time progression. So he didn't actually age.

Comment: If this is a sci-fi story about time travel, and the characters are familiar with it, you could make up a term that they use. SF often coins new terms like this.

Comment: What's wrong with *time-travel* the verb? *With this jump, I time-traveled 15 seconds into the future!* Or just *With this jump, I traveled into the future?* Note that you can time-travel, or travel, backward or forward: deploy an adverb(ial) for direction.

Comment: Don't discount the use of brand names.  If someone were to say they would "Uber into town" their mode of travel is understood.

Comment: @Jason While *Uber* can be verbed (and other things like *Hoover, Scotch, Sellotape, Velcro* have become common nouns) I must have missed the announcement from whoever now makes time machines.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually *to age* works! it would be a bit weird but I like it better than making up a term.

Answer (score 1):

With this jump I skipped 15 seconds.

> skip: *verb*
>
> 3.
>       omit (part of a book that one is reading, or a stage in a sequence that one is following).
>       "the video manual allows the viewer to skip sections he's not interested in"
>
> 4.
>       fail to attend or deal with as appropriate; miss.
>       "I wanted to skip my English lesson to visit my mother"

Comment: I guess that would make Captain Jack Harkness a skipper.